# Django contact form not rendering in template

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I've been stuck with this problem for couple of days now. I have searched the internet and even stackoverflow but couldn't find the solution, I would appreciate all help I can get on this. I am very new to programming, and trying to create a contact form so that users can send emails to registered users using contact form. When I open the page on the browser only the 'Send your message' and the submit button were displayed. The actual form did not.

I have the following codes: PS, I imported all the required modules.

forms.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

views.py:

```
def profile_contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pc_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if pc_form.is_valid():
            sender_name = pc_form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            sender_email = pc_form.cleaned_data['contact_email']

            message = "{0} has sent you a new message:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, pc_form.cleaned_data['content'])
            send_mail('New Enquiry', message, sender_email, ['enquiry@exampleco.com'])

        return redirect('home')
    else:
        pc_form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact_profile.html', {'form': pc_form})
```

urls.py:

```
path('profile_contact/', user_view.profile_contact, name='profile_contact'),
```

contact_profile.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Send your message</legend>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ pc_form | crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" 
type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views.py when rendering a page you use {'form': pc_form} while in html you refering to form as {{ pc_form | crispy }}. Change 'form' to 'pc_form'.

Comment: Great! You're welcome to accept the answer to develop community ;)